# Rails Geocoding on Existing Model to Interactive View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, geocoding, gmaps4rails, rails-geocoder

I'm having some serious challenges understanding how Geocoding works with Rails and I can't seem to locate an answer anywhere as to where I'm going wrong in this specific case.

I'm working on an app that has Events, who each have a location that a User (through Devise) will type in as an address (fields: address + city + state). My goal is to geocode that address after the User submits the form ,and then once someone goes to the Event page display it on an interactive Google map using the Events#show controller.

My original thinking was to Geocode the address using the Geocoder gem upon form submission, and then pass the newly created longitude and latitude from the event model through the gmaps4rails gem to the Google API, and then have it send back the map. No dice so far.

Here's the relevant code I have, and I'm not sure what's going wrong anymore. The "acts_as_gmappable" gives me errors, I can't "rails generate gmaps4rails:install" in the terminal, and I did add the GMAP boolean to the Event schema to no effect. I tried to do it all with Geocoder at first, and that proved nigh impossible with my understanding of the documentation. Any help would be appreciated.

Gemfile

```
gem 'geocoder'
gem 'gmaps4rails'
```

Event.rb

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base

acts_as_gmappable

belongs_to :user

validates :location, :address, :city, :state, :latitude, :longitude, presence: true


geocoded_by :full_address
after_validation :geocode, if: ->(obj){ obj.address.present? and obj.address_changed? }

def full_address
 [street, city, state].compact.join(', ')
end

end
```

Events_Controller.rb

```
def show
@json = Event.to_gmaps4rails
respond_to do |format|
  format.html # show.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @event }
end
end
```

Event Show.HTML.erb

```
<div id="map-container">
<div id="map">
<%= gmaps4rails(@json) %>
</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
 handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
 handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
 markers = handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash.to_json %>);
 handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
 handler.fitMapToBounds();
 });
</script>
```

Initializer Geocoder.rb

```
Geocoder.configure(
:timeout      => 3,           # geocoding service timeout (secs)
:lookup       => :google,     # name of geocoding service (symbol)
:api_key      => "xxxxxxx",
:cache_prefix => "geocoder:", # prefix (string) to use for all cache keys
```

Comment: since v2.x, gmaps4rails doesnt provide geocoding anymore, I explain why here: https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Why-but-why%3F Geocoder geocodes, gmaps4rails displays data

Comment: That's great, and what I figured, so hence my problems here. Here, gmaps4rails isn't displaying the data, and I'm not sure why.

Comment: Please check the wiki, there is even an updated video

Comment: I checked the Wiki and watched the video, twice now. I'm not trying to be a jerk, yet it doesn't seem like you read the actual question. Neither the video nor wiki seems to help with this kind of implementation, where you take an address, geocode it in another gem, and then bring that into gmaps4rails. If you have anything towards that end, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: this is the updated tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R0l-7en3dUw&feature=youtu.be